# Where does the Discord app store tokens?

Tags: discord

I am experimenting with my own Discord client (yes, I know, they are against TOS) and I want to try out automatic account detection. Where does discord keep your tokens or auth keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. You could

1. launch the default client,
2. obtain the process id,
3. use `strace` (Linux) or `lsof` (Linux/Mac) to check which files are accessed.

You may want to combine these steps in a shell script in order to avoid a large delay between launch and attaching `strace`/`lsof`, otherwise early access to some files might go undetected.

Comment: Thank you. For people that stumble across this post, I used this youtube video (https://youtu.be/EG0ihttnEJI) to learn how to use strace. I will update this comment with more info as soon as I go through the strace output file.  (for windows, everything is in %appdata%)

Comment: So...Discord's stuff on Linux is stored in `~/.config/discord`. The auth tokens are in ~/.config/discord/Local\ Storage/leveldb`. To actually find the auth token you'll have to use this piece of python code.
https://pastebin.com/LdhTqHm0